# Передача данных по экранам Swift c 1 на 5

Tags: ios, swift

У меня есть 5 экранов, которые открываются последовательно. Мне нужно получить **данные с первого экрана в пятый**, как передать их не передавая данные в 2,3,4 экраны на swift.
На архитектуре VIPER?